# Delete from a Linked Server

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-2000

I can't figure out how to delete rows from a linked server. My datasource is a mdb file. Here is how I created the linked server:

I was able to insert a couple of rows or update a rows or select rows.

select * from TrainingFeedback...feedback#txt

But how in the world to I delete some or all rows? When I run this:

delete from TrainingFeedback...feedback#txt

I get this error:

Server: Msg 7346, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Could not get the data of the row from the OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'. 
[OLE/DB provider returned message: Bookmark is invalid.]
OLE DB error trace [OLE/DB Provider 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' IRowset::GetData returned 0x80040e0e].

Pls help me for resolved this problem

Answer (score 0):

The provider may not return rows for a delete statement. Try using the "OpenQuery" function to resolve the error. Also, have you tested that the delete did not happen or are you assuming it did not occur because of the error?

[Reference!](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q270119)